# Find by the first characters of a string with a variable mongodb, nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find, var

I want to find a document in my mongodb database by the first characters.

I have a string in my document like this:

```
name: 'Georges'
```

This name is generate just before but it can be too long until 16MB !
So its too long to do a find on a string of 16 MB.
So I have the name in a variable

```
var name = 'Georges'
```

I do a insert in my database. And I want to find it with the characters.
For example :

```
  var query = {name: /^Geo/};
  res = await db.collection('people').find(query).toArray());
```

And its works like that but I want this :

```
var first = 'Geo';
var query = {name: /^first/};
res = await db.collection('people').find(query).toArray());
```

But it cant work because its a variable, not a string.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use `RegExp`

```
var first = 'Geo';
var regex = new RegExp("^" + first, "g");
var query = {name: regex};
```